# Merge Array of Objects by Property using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash

I have two arrays of objects that represent email addresses that have a label and a value:

```
var original = [
  {
    label: 'private',
    value: 'private@johndoe.com'
  },
  {
    label: 'work',
    value: 'work@johndoe.com'
  }
];

var update = [
  {
    label: 'private',
    value: 'me@johndoe.com'
  },
  {
    label: 'school',
    value: 'schhol@johndoe.com'
  }
];
```

Now I want to compare and merge the two arrays by the `label` field, so that the result would look like this:

```
var result = [
  {
    label: 'private',
    value: 'me@johndoe.com'
  },
  {
    label: 'work',
    value: 'work@johndoe.com'
  },
  {
    label: 'school',
    value: 'schol@johndoe.com'
  }
]
```

How can I do this e.g. using [lodash](https://lodash.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: it is not because whether the compared elements are objects or strings makes a big difference in what can be used.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

[`_.unionBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#unionBy):
This method is like _.union except that it accepts iteratee which is invoked for each element of each arrays to generate the criterion by which uniqueness is computed. **Result values are chosen from the first array in which the value occurs**.

```js
var original = [
  { label: 'private', value: 'private@johndoe.com' },
  { label: 'work', value: 'work@johndoe.com' }
];

var update = [
  { label: 'private', value: 'me@johndoe.com' },
  { label: 'school', value: 'schol@johndoe.com' }
];

var result = _.unionBy(update, original, "label");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is very clean

Comment: @Andreas Little follow-up question: How can I achieve the same result, but when the objects in the array contain another object as value? So for example: `[
  { label: 'private', value: {propa: 'some text', propb: 12}}
]` I want the result to merge, so that if the label is the same the properties from the original value get merged with the properties from the new value.

Comment: what if the property name in both array is different?

Comment: what if I have 20 or more arrays? I can't find a way to dynamically pass the arrays as arguments in a loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Convert the lists to objects keyed by `label`, merge them by `_.assign`, and convert it back to an array. It will even retain order of the items on most browsers.

```js
var original = [
  {
    label: 'private',
    value: 'private@johndoe.com'
  },
  {
    label: 'work',
    value: 'work@johndoe.com'
  }
];

var update = [
  {
    label: 'private',
    value: 'me@johndoe.com'
  },
  {
    label: 'school',
    value: 'schol@johndoe.com'
  }
];

console.log(
  _.map(
    _.assign(
      _.mapKeys(original, v => v.label),
      _.mapKeys(update, v => v.label)
    )
  )
);


// or remove more duplicated code using spread

console.log(
  _.map(
    _.assign(
      ...[original, update].map(
        coll => _.mapKeys(coll, v => v.label)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but the solution using _.unionBy() seems to be a little cleaner. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, I almost cried of happyness when saw it. So simple, feels like lodash has a function for everything :)

Comment: That's true ;-) Sometimes you just loose the overview.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit late, but all the solutions I have seen don't join both arrays correctly, they use one of the arrays to loop on and any excess elements in the second array don't get added (assuming this is what is required).

The right way is to sort both arrays and move forward within both arrays, merging the matches elements and adding the missing elements from both arrays.
Please find full solution below. This also takes O(n+m) which is the best you can get (without the computational costs for sort itself). In my code I already got the data sorted from the database.

```js
function mergeObjectsBasedOnKey(array1, array2, compareFn, mergeFn, alreadySorted) {
  var array1Index = 0;
  var array2Index = 0;

  const merged = [];

  if (!alreadySorted) {
    array1.sort(compareFn);
    array2.sort(compareFn);
  }

  while (array1Index < array1.length && array2Index < array2.length) {
    var comparedValue = compareFn(array1[array1Index], array2[array2Index]);
    if (comparedValue === 0) {
      merged.push(mergeFn(array1[array1Index], array2[array2Index]));
      array1Index++;
      array2Index++;
    } else if (comparedValue < 0) {
      merged.push(mergeFn(array1[array1Index]));
      array1Index++;
    } else {
      merged.push(mergeFn(array2[array2Index]));
      array2Index++;
    }
  }
  while (array1Index < array1.length) {
    merged.push(mergeFn(array1[array1Index]));
    array1Index++;
  }
  while (array2Index < array2.length) {
    merged.push(mergeFn(array2[array2Index]));
    array2Index++;
  }
  return merged;
}


const array1 = [{
    "id": 10,
    isArray1: true
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    isArray1: true
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    isArray1: true
  },
];
const array2 = [{
    "id": 8,
    isArray2: true
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    isArray2: true
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    isArray2: true
  },
];

const result = mergeObjectsBasedOnKey(array1, array2, function(a, b) {
  return a.id - b.id;
}, function(a, b) {
  if (b) {
    return _.merge(a, b);
  }
  return _.merge(a, {
    isArray1: true,
    isArray2: true
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the results would be:

```
[ { id: 8, isArray2: true, isArray1: true },
  { id: 10, isArray1: true, isArray2: true },
  { id: 11, isArray1: true, isArray2: true },
  { id: 12, isArray1: true, isArray2: true },
  { id: 15, isArray2: true, isArray1: true } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using lodash 3.x where **_.unionBy()** was not there, you can combine `_.union()` and `_.uniq()` to get the same result.

```
var original = [
  { label: 'private', value: 'private@johndoe.com' },
  { label: 'work', value: 'work@johndoe.com' }
];

var update = [
  { label: 'private', value: 'me@johndoe.com' },
  { label: 'school', value: 'schol@johndoe.com' }
];

var result = _.uniq(_.union(update, original), "label"); 

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is not what asked for but just in case someone stumbled up on this page here is how you do this in ramda:

```
var original = [
  { label: 'private', value: 'private@johndoe.com' },
  { label: 'work', value: 'work@johndoe.com' }
];

var updated = [
  { label: 'private', value: 'me@johndoe.com' },
  { label: 'school', value: 'schol@johndoe.com' }
];

unionWith(eqBy(prop('label')), updated, original);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to merge two objects using Lodash:

```js
let a = [{
    content: 'aaa',
    name: 'bbb2'
  },
  {
    content: 'aad',
    name: 'ccd'
  }
];

let b = [{
    content: 'aaa',
    name: 'bbb'
  },
  {
    content: 'aad1',
    name: 'ccd1'
  }
];

let c = [...a, ...b];

let d = _.uniq(c, function(data) {
  return data.content;
})

console.log(d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps a bit late, but all the solutions I have seen don't join both arrays correctly, they use one of the arrays to loop on and any excess elements in the second array don't get added (assuming this is what is required).

I had the same observation so put something together myself. This is working for my use case, which is to merge each object if the value of the 'label' field matches:

```
const dataSetHashes = dataSets.map(dataSet => _.keyBy(dataSet, 'label'))
const resultHash = _.merge(
  {},
  ...dataSetLookups
)
const result = Object.values(resultLookup)
```