# Add object contents in one object array within objects in another array

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I have two large files containing object arrays, the first containing data like this:

```
[{
    "id": "001",
    "word": "abbess",
    "def": "(noun) The lady superior of a nunnery",
}, {
    "id": "002"
    "word": "abbey",
    "def": "(noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",
}, (etc...)
```

The second, data like this:

```
[{
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbess",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The lady superior of a nunnery"
    }
}, {
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbey",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns"
    }
}, (etc...)
```

I want to combine these two files so the "meta" information from the second file is added to the corresponding information from the first file, so:

```
[{
    "id": "001",
    "word": "abbess",
    "def": "(noun) The lady superior of a nunnery",
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbess",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The lady superior of a nunnery"
    }
}, {
    "id": "002"
    "word": "abbey - (noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",
    "def": "(noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbey",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns"
    }
}, (etc...)
```

Right now, I'm have this code

```
 var newArr = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < meta.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(words[i]);
    newArr.push(meta[i]);
 }
```

that adds the meta objects after the words object, not within. Do I need to loop down another layer to add the meta objects within the words objects, or is there a different method that would work better here, like .concat()?

Comment: Do the two arrays line up? In other words does `meta[0]` always go with `data[0]`, `meta[1]` with `data[1]` , etc?

Comment: `words.forEach((w, ix) => w.info = meta[ix].info)`

Comment: @Keith That mutates the original objects.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Yes, I know.   -> `the second file is added to the corresponding information from the first file`

Comment: The order of both arrays is the same index `0` from A is the same in index `0` in `B`?

Comment: @Mark_M Yes, the arrays do line up.

Comment: Perform the answer to [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](//stackoverflow.com/q/171251) in a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge objects inside the two arrays using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811775/merge-objects-inside-the-two-arrays-using-lodash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the new property of the object from the first array.

```
 var newArr = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < meta.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    word.meta = meta[i].meta;
    newArr.push(word);
 }
```

This is assuming that both arrays will always have info of the same word in the same order.

Bonus tip - if you are using ECMAScript 6, you could concatenate the objects like this:

```
 const newArr = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < meta.length; i++) {
    newArr.push({ ...words[i], ...meta[i]} );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If each element in each array corresponds to the other element with the same index in the other array, then it's a simple `.map`, which is more appropriate than a `for` loop:

```js
const input1 = [{
    "id": "001",
    "word": "abbess",
    "def": "(noun) The lady superior of a nunnery",
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "word": "abbey",
    "def": "(noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",
}];
const input2 = [{
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbess",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The lady superior of a nunnery"
    }
}, {
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbey",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns"
    }
}];
const combined = input1.map((item) => {
  const { word } = item ;
  const foundInput2 = input2.find(({ meta: { term }}) => term === word);
  const { meta } = foundInput2;
  return { ...item, meta };
});
console.log(combined);
```

Comment: I like your answer, I am still getting used to using Map(), could you take your map functionality to compare the term to word properties and look for string equality so you don't have to depend on the indexes being the same?

Comment: Easy to tweak, just use `.find` to find the other object instead

Comment: Thanks for that snippet. Still trying to get used to the llambda syntax in javascript, been using it in C# more so I'm starting to be able to read it pretty well. Didn't know you could do a return statement like that concatinating the objects together, +1 from me sir.

Answer (score 2):

loop through the array of metas and use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add the meta to the corresponding object in the first array :

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "001",
  "word": "abbess",
  "def": "(noun) The lady superior of a nunnery",
}, {
  "id": "002",
  "word": "abbey",
  "def": "(noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",
}]

const arr2 = [{
  "meta": {
    "term": "abbess",
    "part_of_speech": "noun",
    "definition": "The lady superior of a nunnery"
  }
}, {
  "meta": {
    "term": "abbey",
    "part_of_speech": "noun",
    "definition": "The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns"
  }
}]

arr2.forEach((e, i) => {
  Object.assign(arr[i], e);
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the arrays doesn't line up, you can use `.map` and `.find` to achieve your goal.

```js
const input1 = [{
    "id": "001",
    "word": "abbess",
    "def": "(noun) The lady superior of a nunnery",
}, {
    "id": "002",
    "word": "abbey",
    "def": "(noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",
}];
const input2 = [{
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbess",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The lady superior of a nunnery"
    }
}, {
    "meta": {
        "term": "abbey",
        "part_of_speech": "noun",
        "definition": "The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns"
    }
}];

const output = input1.map(item => {
    return { 
      ...item, 
      ...input2.find(item2 => item2.meta.term === item.word)
    }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` + function `map`

The function `reduce` converts the second array `input2` to an object where keys are coming from the attribute `meta.term`, this way the function `map` uses that object to find very fast the corresponding meta values by key rather than a repeated `find` execution.

This approach works independently of the order because will match the attributes `word` and attributes `meta.term`.

```js
const input1 = [{    "id": "001",    "word": "abbess",    "def": "(noun) The lady superior of a nunnery",}, {    "id": "002",    "word": "abbey",    "def": "(noun) The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns.",}],
      input2 = [{    "meta": {        "term": "abbess",        "part_of_speech": "noun",        "definition": "The lady superior of a nunnery"    }}, {    "meta": {        "term": "abbey",        "part_of_speech": "noun",        "definition": "The group of buildings which collectively form the dwelling-place of a society of monks or nuns"    }}],
      mapped = input2.reduce((a, o) => Object.assign(a, {[o.meta.term]: o.meta}), {}),
      result = input1.map((o) => Object.assign({}, o, {meta: mapped[o.word]}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```