# merge 2 array and replace same key using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

i have this 2 array,

```
const firstArray = [
{
 key: 'a',
 value: 'a'
},
{
 key: 'b',
 value: 'b'
},
{
 key: 'c',
 value: 'c'
}
]

const secondArray = [
{
 key: 'b',
 value: 'd'
},
{
 key: 'c',
 value: 'e'
}
]
```

i want to merge these 2 array, and if a same key found on second array the second array value will replace first array value

the new array should look like this

```
const expectedArray = [
{
 key: 'a',
 value: 'a'
},
{
 key: 'b',
 value: 'd'
},
{
 key: 'c',
 value: 'e'
}
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849286/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-a-key)

Comment: also [Merge Array of Objects by Property using Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127565/merge-array-of-objects-by-property-using-lodash/39127782)

Comment: i think the second one is similar with mine, sorry i think i use wrong keyword when searching before post this question, @pilchard

Comment: no worries, it's okay to have duplicates but also good that they get linked as such to make a bigger pool of related answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see `lodash` in your tags, I assume you want to use it.

You can use something like this:

```js
var merged = _(firstArray)
  .concat(secondArray)
  .groupBy("key")
  .map(_.spread(_.merge))
  .value();
```

It basically groups all objects with the same key into an array with `groupBy("key")`, then flattens out each array of values merging them and taking the last one with `.map(_.spread(_.merge))`.

I suggest commenting out the final likes and see all the intermediate steps if you want to fully understand the process, it's interesting!

```js
const firstArray = [{
    key: 'a',
    value: 'a'
  },
  {
    key: 'b',
    value: 'b'
  },
  {
    key: 'c',
    value: 'c'
  }
]

const secondArray = [{
    key: 'b',
    value: 'd'
  },
  {
    key: 'c',
    value: 'e'
  }
]

var merged = _(firstArray)
  .concat(secondArray)
  .groupBy("key")
  .map(_.spread(_.merge))
  .value();

console.log(merged);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wanna ask about the `_.spread(_.merge)`. so the spread will run merge for each description, and for `key a` since its just have one object inside, its just return same  object, but for key b and c, because it have 2 object inside each key, it will be return last object. am i right?

Comment: Yes, at that point all items of each mapped array will have the same `key` value so it does not change, but for `description` (and more fields if there are) it will merge them all and take the last value.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without `lodash` is to iterate through the second array and just look for matches.

If there's no match, push the item to the first array.

If there's a match, replace the item in the first array with the one from the second array.

```js
const mergedArray = [...firstArray]

secondArray.forEach(newItem => {
  const matchIndex = mergedArray.findIndex(prevItem => prevItem.key === newItem.key)

  if (matchIndex === -1) {
    mergedArray.push(newItem)
  } else {
    mergedArray[matchIndex] = newItem
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mergedArray = [...secondArray, ...firstArray];
const lengthOfUniqueArray = new Set(mergedArray.map((item) => item.key)).size;
const expectedArray = newArray.slice(0, lengthOfUniqueArray);
```

`expectedArray` will be what you want.

Comment: This will allow multiple items with the same `key` to be in the `expectedArray`, which is not what was asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat, reverse, can all unique elements by key, and then reverse back:

```js
const { flow, concat, reverse, uniqBy } = _

const mergeArrays = flow(
  concat,
  reverse,
  arr => uniqBy(arr, 'key'),
  reverse
)

const firstArray = [{"key":"a","value":"a"},{"key":"b","value":"b"},{"key":"c","value":"c"}]
const secondArray = [{"key":"b","value":"d"},{"key":"c","value":"e"}]

var merged = mergeArrays(firstArray, secondArray)

console.log(merged)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if i didnt need to have every key in same order, it should be ok to remove the reverse right?

Comment: The reverse is needed, if you want to take to duplicate from the 2nd array.